why using ffplay to play a video nothing went error but don't show any thing
env:WSL2 UBuntu 22.04 ffmpeg6.1.2 SDL2.28.3


Do you hear audio? (if there is any audio in the video)

video has audio ,i using normal player like VLC is ok .but it don't work on my WSL ffplay. The most important thing is the video don't show,but nothing wrong printf.

XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

Please read why we ask that you not post text as images.  Please
[Edit] your post
to include the text in-addition-to or in-place-of the image.  Thanks!

Also, please read How do I ask a good question?, especially the part about "Search ... And Research".  Please tell us what you have searched on so far and what you have tried, even if it didn't work. Doing so helps us not waste your time (and ours) by suggesting solutions you've already tried. For instance, have you tried addressing the error message about XDG_RUNTIME_DIR?
